# Grafana cutting curves

Tags: limit, influxdb, grafana

After an update to Grafana v4.1.2 (commit: v4.1.2) which I am using together with the latest version of InfluxDB my dashboards changed their behaviour.
I am not using GROUP BY time($interval) in this particular dashboard, but give the possibility to define the group by value via template variable: GROUP BY time($group_time)

I know this is risky, but under our certain circumstances it needs to be this way.

Before the update if a very small value for group by variable was chosen together with a vast time interval obviously or it took a very long time to load or the Browser went in tilt. Now this behaviour changed. There seems to be a limit on the datapoints that grafana visualizes/ retrieves. To make this clearer see the example below:

Time interval with 20s GROUP BY
[image]
both curves entirely visible with this group by value

Same Time intervall with 10s GROUP BY
[image]
one curve entirely visible with this group by value, other curve cut after some points

Same Time intervall with 10s GROUP BY first curve turned to invisible
[image]
the second curve is entirely visible again

I suspect, that Grafana is now sending a LIMIT to InfluxDB. I found this bit of information for the combination Grafana & Graphite http://docs.grafana.org/installation/performance/ but nothing for Grafana & InfluxDB.

So where has this been changed and is there a way to set this limit manually? The limit that I am experiencing at the moment is most probably 10000, because I can limit my queries with values below 10000, but any higher value does not bring more points. Any kind of documentation of this now default limit would be very much appreciated.

Comment: the request to grafana is sent via HTTP, so you should be able to check whether grafana actually send a limit in the query requests using browser debug tools. From my experience with other datasources, grafana sets a limit of ~1900 datapoints per timeseries (not sure if this actually depends on screen resolution, but it would make sort of sense)

Comment: Maybe related to this recent change in InfluxDB? https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/7380

Comment: in ChromeDevTools the queries send do not contain any LIMIT but the amount of data received back is not increasing any more when we are > 10000 points so I think you are dead right with the InfluxDB change mentioned above, I am investigating a bit further in that direction now, thanks so far!